# A space X of Riemannian metrics of a given manifold M in a vector space of symmetric bilinear forms on M, prove X is an infinite dimensional cone.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, manifolds

I want to understand if the space X of Riemannian metrics of a given manifold M is an infinite dimensional cone in a vector space of symmetric bilinear forms 0n M. Also is the cone compact?

Comment: What did you try and where did the difficulty occur? Do you have trouble with the cone part or the convexity part? Can you prove that the space of positive definite matrices is a convex cone in the space of symmetric matrices?